# Pytesseract Failed loading language 'chi-sim'

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on python tesseract package with sample code like the follows:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

tessdata_dir_config = "--tessdata-dir \"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract-lang/4.1.0/share/tessdata/\""
image = Image.open("dataset/test.jpeg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = "chi-sim", config = tessdata_dir_config)
print(text)
```

And I received the following error message:

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract-lang/4.1.0/share/tessdata/chi-sim.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'chi-sim' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

From my understanding, the error occurred when reading the file `chi-sim.traineddata` (which stands for Simplified Chinese), as I will explain the attempts I have made to settle this problem below.

- My developing environment is M1 macOS, and I installed `tesseract` and `tesseract-lang` from Homebrew. I am pretty sure that the path specified above is exactly where the source files are located, since when I call

```
print(pytesseract.get_languages(config = ""))
```

I get a long list of languages printed, including chi-sim.

- Further, if we just use English instead of Chinese, the following code can successfully recognize the English texts in an image:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

- I've tried to specify environment variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` in multiple ways, including:

1. Using `config` parameter as in the original code.
2. Adding global environment variable in PyCharm.
3. Adding the following line in the code

```
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = "tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/"
```

4. Adding the following line to `bash_profile` in terminal

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract-lang/4.1.0/share/tessdata/
```

But unfortunately, none of these works.

- It seems as if my file `chi-sim.traineddata` is, somehow, broken, so I directly downloaded the trained data file from GitHub (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/chi_sim.traineddata), hit the "Download" button on the right, and placed the downloaded file in the tesseract-lang and original tesseract directory (where `eng.traineddata` is located). Yes, I've tried both, but neither works.

With respect to this issue, is there any potential solutions?

Comment: If you are on windows, did you setup the environmental PATH for tesseract?

Comment: Never mind, just read that you are on Mac OS, so have you tried reinstalling the whole package?

Comment: if `get_languages(config = "")` shows `chi-sim` then why do you set `tessdata-dir`? Did you try without changing `tessdata-dir`?

Comment: if `chi-sim.traineddata` is broken then you have to download it again. You don't need to change `tessdata-dir` - even error shows that it is correct - but you have to get correct file from server.

Comment: Also, what is your language setting in your Mac OS? There used to be some issue with non-English system language for tesseract

Comment: in question (not in comment) you could add link to GitHub where you found `chi-sim.traineddata` - and you could describe how you downloaded it. Maybe you download it in wrong way (i.e in `text-mode` instead of `bytes-mode`) or maybe you get files for older version - see GitHub with [tessdata for 4.x](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) there is link to [tessdata for 3.x](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00)

Comment: @seraph Yes, I've tried reinstalling pytesseract, tesseract-lang, and tesseract at the same time, but did not work.

Comment: @furas Yes, the first line of code I ran was indeed without the "config = tessdata_dir" parameter, but it did not work, so I had to resort to specifying directories.

Comment: @seraph Hmmm... this is a good point because my general language setting of my device is chi-sim. I will check it out later and update this post if there's anything good.

Comment: @furas Sorry that I could not find the exact github link that I downloaded previously, I just tried the 4.x you provided but it does not work either. I've edited my question. But could you please explain a little bit on "text mode" and "bytes mode"? I was never aware of these.

Comment: I copied original `eng.traineddata` and file from server`chi-sim.traineddata` to new folder and try `lang="chi-sim"` and `lang="eng"` with `config="--tessdata-dir path/to/new/folder"` and it works for `eng` but not for `chi-sim` - it may means that `chi-sim.traineddata` is wrong. Maybe it is broken already on server. Or maybe it is file for older tesseract. I will check if `eng.traineddata` from server makes this problem. Maybe it will need to send information to authors that there is problem.

Comment: code works for me on LInux if I use `chi_sim` with `_` instead of `-` because file downloaded from server has name `chi_sim.traineddata` also with `_`

Comment: @furas interesting, upon checking tessdata on github, it does shows the datapacks with `_` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works for me on Linux if I use `lang="chi_sim"` with `_` instead of `-` because file downloaded from server has name `chi_sim.traineddata` also with `_` instead of `-`.

---

If I rename file into `chi-sim.traineddata` then I can use `lang="chi-sim"` (with `-` instead of `_`)